# Unsure how to use jQuery UI dialog modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use the jQuery UI plugin http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/ so I've got everything I need downloaded. I've put the files where they need to be and included them in the `<head>` like I'm supposed to - all no problems there. But next I get a little stuck due to my utter noobieness.

It says:

> Once you've included the necessary files, you can add some jQuery widgets to your page. For example, to make a datepicker widget, you'll add a text input element to your page and then call .datepicker(); on it. Like this: **HTML:** `<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />`
>
> **JS:**
>
> `$('#date').datepicker();`

I want to use the dialog modal window popup with a form in it they've got as a demo. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form. The form will popup when someone clicks an image.

As far as I can make out (I'm a beginner with JavaScript) I need to make a hidden div on my page which contains the form. I need to attach it somehow to JavaScript then need to call it when the user clicks the image.

I have no idea if that's right or wrong. And if it's right I dunno how to do it. Anyone fancy speeding me along with some directions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/expertCode/gTPnz/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img alt="exampleImage" src="http://www.cancercareofwnc.com/Images/topmenu_testing_0.gif">

    <div id="myDiv">
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
            <input type="text" name="other" id="other" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#myDiv{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img[alt="exampleImage"]').click(function(){
        $('#myForm').dialog();
    });                          
});
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to use that particular plugin tho. Or at least if it does I don't understand it. The javascript for the plugin is waaaay bigger than just what you have. Can't be the same thing surely?

Comment: To works, you need to include in your project, last version of jQuery, and jQuery UI. After that you can use that Widgets, for example, like the dialog(). To know how those libraries works, you have good documentations explaining all the things: 
- [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)
- [jQuery UI Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI)
It was it what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 0):

So, your hidden div could have a class `.noshow`

You could add to your css:

```
`.noshow` {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Then, in your js,

```
$('#mylink').click(function() {
  $('#hiddenForm').removeClass('noshow').dialog({ modal: true });
});
```

Should work...

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the response but although this does produce sorta what I want it doesn't explain specifically how to use the plugin.